# Amazon EC2 refused to connect, although port 80 is open, and SSH works fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

My EC2 instance has been working well with no problem for many years, but after Amazon's recent maintenance, the webpage cannot be reached. Chrome browser says:

This site can’t be reached (the below is the error that I see at Chrome)

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

SSH port (22) works fine; I can connect it with Cyberduck as usual. However other ports (80, 8080) do not work, although the security group has inbound rule to accept any IPs for the HTTP.

Edit: per request, this is what I see in my ec2 (connected with my pem key on Terminal)

```
$ netstat -an | grep 80
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     8017   @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    8026   
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    8025
```

I see "80"s are bold and red.

Comment: Is your web server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) running?

Comment: Do you have elastic IP attached to the instance? If not, you will get a new public address after maintenance, make sure you are using the correct public IP.

Comment: I think he is using correct IP address as he have mentioned that he can SSH to the box.

Comment: Inside this ec2 instance, could you run `netstat -an | grep 80` and [edit] your question to include the output?

Comment: @Kenster thank you, I edited the question. yes, it's Linux server on t2.micro, and it's running well with elastic IP.

Comment: According to the netstat output, you don't have anything listening for connections on port 80. IOW, your web server software isn't running or it's running but listening on a different port. I don't have experience with ec2 to give detailed instructions on fixing this.

Comment: Presumably the EC2 instance rebooted during maintenance. Does your web server automatically start up at boot time?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you so much for the answers. The LAMP server didn't start after the reboot. I had to do restart the server by "sudo service httpd start" Maybe I should find a way to start the server automatically after each reboot?

Comment: @Kenster thank you so much. surely helped!!

Comment: Use the chkconfig command to configure the Apache web server to start at each system boot: sudo chkconfig httpd on.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the EC2 instance rebooted during maintenance and your web server is not set up to auto restart.

Use the chkconfig command to configure the Apache web server to start at each system boot: `sudo chkconfig httpd on`.